# Change fill color of cell when clicked in Processing

Tags: arrays, colors, click, processing

I've managed to print the co-ordinates of a cell when it's clicked.

Now I'm looking for help and advice to use the this data in order to change the cell colour to red - unless the cell selected is a base cell, I want those to remain as a constant. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
Tile[][] tileArray = new Tile[10][10];


int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;
int[] base = { 4,4, 4,5, 4,6, 4,7 };

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      tileArray[i][j] = new Tile(i*50, j*50);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  for (int i=0; i<base.length; i+=2) {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    rect(base[i]*50, base[i+1]*50, 50, 50);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      println (mouseX/50 +"," + mouseY/50);
    }
  }
}

class Tile {
  Tile(int x, int y) {
    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I've added the functionality which I am looking for, but I assume that I have not stored my base cell data correctly. As you can still click on the base cell and an active cell is drawing underneath. Here is the new code:

```
Tile[][] tiles;
int gridSize = 10;
int tileSize = 50;


void setup() {
  size (450, 400);
  generateGrid();
}

void draw() {
  background (255);
  display();
}

public void generateGrid() {
  tiles = new Tile[gridSize][gridSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
      tiles[i][j] = new Tile((i*50), (j*50), tileSize, tileSize);
    }
  }
}


public void display() {
  for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
      tiles[i][j].display();
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
      println (mouseX/50 +"," + mouseY/50);
    }
  }

  int mx = mouseX/50;
  int my = mouseY/50;
  tiles[mx][my].active = !tiles[mx][my].active;
  //      tiles[mx][my].base = !tiles[mx][my].base;      
  println(tiles[mx][my].active);
}

class Tile {
  int tx, ty, tw, th;
  int[] baseCell = { 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5 };

  color col_default = color(255);
  color col_base = color(0, 0, 255);
  color col_active  = color(255, 100, 50);

  boolean active = false;
  boolean base = false;


  Tile (int itx, int ity, int itw, int ith) {
    tx = itx;
    ty = ity;
    tw = itw;
    th = ith;
  }

  void display() {  
    stroke(0);   
    fill(col_default);

    if ( active )      fill (col_active); 

    rect(tx, ty, tw, th);

    for (int i=0; i<baseCell.length; i+=2) {
      fill(col_base);
      rect(baseCell[i]*50, baseCell[i+1]*50, 50, 50);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Tile class doesn't really make sense right now. It doesn't really make sense to draw to the screen from a constructor. Instead, move that logic into a `draw()` function inside the `Tile` class.

Your `Tile` class also has to keep track of its state: whether it's a base cell or not, or any other kind of cell it can be. You might do this with an enum, or an int, or a set of booleans. That part is completely up to you.

Then in your `Tile.draw()` function, you should check that state to decide what color to draw. From the sketch's `draw()` function, simply loop over each `Tile` and tell it to draw itself.

Finally, when you click, simply set the state of the `Tile` that you clicked on.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense, I've managed to find similar functionality to the logic that you described and have edited it to fit my needs. Although I am unsure how to store the base cell data in the Tile class. 
Currently I have it in the draw function and I assume this is not the best practise. I have edited the post to show my new code.

Comment: Actually, playing around I think I have managed to get it right. Could you again tell me if my code logic is poor? I believe when I click a base cell, an active cell is still trying to draw underneath.